# Why protected members can be overridden by public members in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, typescript

I am new to Typescript, and I tried to played around a little with TypeScript in this [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). I noticed that in TypeScript, a protected member in base class can be overridden by public members:

```
class Base {
    protected name: string = '!'
}

class Derived extends Base{
    public name: string = '?'
}
```

On the one hand, this makes sense to me since the Liskov Substitution Principle still holds: base class has stricter requirements than derived class. But on the other hand, I noticed that private member cannot be overridden by protected or public one, which seems inconsistent to me:

```
class Base {
    private name: string = '!'
}

class Derived extends Base{
    public name: string = '?'  // ERROR!
}
```

Thus I wonder:

1. Is my observation an intended behavior or a bug in Typescript?
2. If it's intended, why this inconsistency exists? Why not TypeScript requires all overriding members having the same accessibility as members in base class? Or allowing all derived members with higher accessibility overriding members in base class?

Comment: Here's the official documentation that gives a clear explanation - 


[Typescriptlang.org - Exposure of protected members]
(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#exposure-of-protected-members)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.

You can make a `protected` field `public` because `protected` allows a derived class to read and write a field. The derived class can choose to use its ability to read and write the field to allow others to read and write the field. There's no point making you write something like this:

```
class Foo {
  protected someField;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  public get someFieldButPublic() {
    return this.someField;
  }
  public set someFieldButPublic(value) {
    this.someField = value;
  }
}
```

if all you wanted to do was make `someField` public.

You can't make a `private` field `protected` or `public` because you don't have read or write access to that field. It's `private`; if the base class wanted you to have access to the field, they would have made it `protected`, after all.

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behavior.

TypeScript compiles to JavaScript. Because of this, using access modifiers in your code has absolutely no effect on the output. The only thing that access modifiers do is let the compiler yell at you if you use something that you shouldn't be accessing.

Example: Both of these classes compile to the exact same code. [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20prop%20is%20_private_%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20prop%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.prop%20%3D%20%22str%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20prop%20is%20_public_%0D%0Aclass%20Test2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20prop%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.prop%20%3D%20%22str%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) (ignore the class name)

```
// prop is private
class Test {
    private prop: string;
    constructor() {
        this.prop = "str"
    }
}

// prop is public
class Test {
    public prop: string;
    constructor() {
        this.prop = "str"
    }
}
```

In languages like C#, private properties are truly private, and thus it is possible to inherit from a class with a private name property while exposing a name property. Inherited methods accessing `this.name` will access the `name` property in the base class, while methods in your class accessing `this.name` will use the property in the inheriting class.

Let's look at the emitted JavaScript for your example.

```
var __extends; // omitted for brevity
var Base = (function () {
    function Base() {
        this.name = '!';
    }
    return Base;
}());
var Derived = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Derived, _super);
    function Derived() {
        var _this = _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
        _this.name = '?';
        return _this;
    }
    return Derived;
}(Base));
```

As you can see, what happens here is the `Base` class assigns `!` to `this.name`, `Derived` then changes the supposedly private `name` property of `Base` to `?`. Obviously, this could result in some *incredibly* confusing bugs when methods in the `Base` class refer to `this.name` and get the unexpected value assigned by the `Derived` class.

Answer (score 0):

javascript has no this capability as in java called it is a field rewrite.let's look a code snippet in java:

```
class Base {
    protected String name = "!";

    public String bar() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public String name = "?";

    public String foo() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

when you hold an a kind of Derived instance `it` in java. then it.foo() return `"?"` and it.bar() return `"!"`.but why both methods return `"?"` in javascript,due to the javascript behavior occurs in runtime and bind `this` type to Derived in Base,so you can't rewrite fields in javascript.Are you remember `Function.prototype.call(thisArg)`?In Derived class that doing something like this,if you call the bar method on Derived instance,it actually bind Derived type to the Base class. you can disallow to do such thing is make the field private in Base and let the compiler tell you this errors only in typescript.

Comment: Sorry. What I am asking is that why public members can override protected members, but cannot override private members. I think you did not really answer my question.

Comment: Since private member is not visible in derived class, why cannot public member just override it as if the private member in base class does not exist? Instead a error is thrown?

Comment: @LifuHuang field is not overriding,it is rewrite.

Comment: @LifuHuang this question is too easy,because protected members can accessed in subclass and then you can promote  access modifier of the member but you can't  down  access modifier of the member in any OO language.

Comment: @LifuHuang and I never called field is overrided by subclass in my answer,I called it rewrite.

Comment: 1. I don't think it has something to do with "rewriting", since the same thing happens for methods; 2. public member overriding private member is still "promoting" access modifier, right?

Comment: @LifuHuang you can use the `tsc` compile typescript into javascript,and see the raw code that is just rewriting fields.