# Why protected inner class of object may be seen outside of its definition scope?

Tags: scala, access-modifiers

Consider the following:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object O {
  protected case class I(x: Int)
  trait T {
    protected def m: I = I(0)
  }
}

val i = new O.T { override def m = super.m }.m

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object O
i: O.I = I(0)

scala> :type i
O.I
```

If I add `: O.I` after `val i` this code snippet fails to compile, but statement `i.x` compiles and returns `0` in runtime.

Is it a compiler bug or there is a good reason for such behavior?

Comment: This works as intended. The type `O.I` can not be used outside `O`. But by making `T` public, you allow and instance of that type to be used. That makes sense, because what is made protected is the access to the identifier as well as its constructor. - Anyways, what exactly you wanted to achieve here? If you want post exactly which access restrictions would you like to have and I will try to see if they are possible to accomplish.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, rather than such a confusing behavior I would like to get a compilation error, e.g. ```error: protected class I escapes its defining scope ...``` when defining trait T.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I found such code in the wild https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.2.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L138.

Comment: Well if you want that, you have to use `private` instead of `protected`.

Comment: Sure, they've switched to ```private[admin]``` later, but the question is about surprising behavior of protected, not about workarounds.

Comment: I think that is because a wrong understanding of protected on inner classes. What it says is that only that class and sub instance of it, can see the symbol type and its constructor. But you are allowed to space instances of such class. Anyways, if you believe that is surprising _(I do too)_the best place to ask about the rationale of that decision would be the **Scala contributors** gitter channel or discord. Instead of SO.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, well, but why does private not work in the same way then?

Comment: please see my updated comment. I agree with you in that that is strange. But I do not think this is the best place to ask for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived classes can in any case [brake protection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43085231/5205022) as they have full access to base class protected members. Consider public method `foo` below

```
val i = new O.T {
  override protected def m = super.m
  def foo = m
}
```

We keep `m` as `protected`, nevertheless `i.foo` indirectly "brakes out" of protection and evaluates to `res0: O.I = I(0)`. So it seems we do not gain much by preventing widening on overriding.

Also consider related answer to [When overriding a method, why can I increase access but not decrease it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851612/when-overriding-a-method-why-can-i-increase-access-but-not-decrease-it):

> It's a fundamental principle in OOP: the child class is a
>   fully-fledged instance of the parent class, and must therefore present
>   **at least** the same interface as the parent class.

Comment: I do it intentionally. I'm surprised that Scala allows me to do it.